# implement multi threading with vb6

Tags: multithreading, vb6

I Have this task of implementing automation process through multiple serial ports attached to the pc.
How can i implement multi threading with vb6 to independently do some automation tasks through the attached serial ports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why in the world would you use VB6 for this? It's obsolete and unsupported.

Comment: Hi john,actually this is a kind of enhancement requirement for the existing vb6 project.

Comment: As Hans's answer indicates, you might as well consider this impossible. Technically, there are hacks that *might* let you use multiple threads in VB 6, but they're so fragile that your application is more likely to blow up than work correctly. The time it would take to implement these and debug all of the problems would be better spent porting your application to VB.NET instead. The biggest mistake people make is treating VB.NET as if it were the same language as VB 6. That's not the case. Take the time to learn the .NET Framework first, port your project in small bits at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.I will look into porting the existing application to .net and then implement multi threading.

Comment: There are some suggestions here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959202/can-one-do-multithreading-in-vb6 but they mostly seem to be recommending you don't do it.

Comment: Other suggestions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383162/to-use-thread-in-programming-in-vb6) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727386/making-a-c-kill-event-for-a-vb6-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, vb6 doesn't support multi-threading.  It sorta worked in vb5 by hacking the winapi but got completely broken in vb6.  The error handling is busted, getting an error in one thread crashes all of them.  Move up to vb.net to get it back.

Comment: Hi Hans,actually this is a kind of enhancement requirement for the existing vb6 project.Once i heard that multi threading is possible with Activex exe.Is that correct? Presently we have service pack 6 installed.

Comment: You can multithread all you want in a component that wasn't written in VB, as long as the VB runtime never sees a thread you created. Don't raise an event from such a thread for example.

Answer (score 3):

Desaware's [SpyWorks product](http://www.desaware.com/products/universalcom/index.aspx) (now sold as UniversalCOM) has a component (dwBackThread) for creating threads in VB6.

Also, check out 'Even Better Multithreading with Low Overhead' ([part1](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=24695&lngWId=1) and [part2](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=24747&lngWId=1)), [ThreadRunner](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=32466&lngWId=1) (4 parts, see authors other posts) and [MThreadVB](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=26900&lngWId=1) for free open source solutions. I have not personally tried these but all were generally well received by the community.

VB6 obviously wasn't designed for threads in the traditional sense, but using either 3rd party components or some creative coding, it can be achieved.

Comment: Definitely. You can +certainly+ do multiple threaded programs in VB6. I built a TCPIP server/client app ages ago that was just that sort of thing. No 3'rd party stuff required, but it did take some wonky COM architecture. Given that, and that VB6 is sunsetted, I'd say I'd also recommend porting to VB.net or some more modern language where threading is more directly supported.

Answer (score 2):

If you avoid the common mistake of writing your program as if you were using QBasic under MS-DOS this usually isn't a problem.

The MSComm control can be used asynchronously, raising OnComm events on input or errors.  Doing this instead of writing buzz-loops polling state (and worse yet calling DoEvents() to try to remain responsive) can eliminate the need for explicit worker threads.

People write TCP servers to good effect this way, managing hundreds or even thousands of simultaneous connections.  You can do the same thing for serial port communication easily, since there are far fewer "connections" to handle at much lower data rates.

You don't need a separate thread for every command button, and in the same way you don't need a thread for each MSComm control.

Comment: Absolutely it does that. You should generally never have to "poll" a serial port for data, whatever serial lib you're working with should raise events/callbacks when data is available. I worked on a Gas station POS once that used polling. It could bring a fast processor to its knees pretty quickly. But there was no need for it. The head dev just didn't know any better.