# Threading In VB 6 !

Tags: vb6

How can we achieve threading in VB 6?  Can someone illustrate with easy example?
Thankx in advance!

Comment: **so** many duplicates to this question! Voting to close. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959202/can-one-do-multithreading-in-vb6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383162/to-use-thread-in-programming-in-vb6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241690/implement-multi-threading-with-vb6

Answer (score 0):

Threading is, by it's nature, not easy.  I caution you to be very careful.

Normally this is done with ActiveX EXE's.  Here's a [good example](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/libraries/Threading/Multi-threading_using_classes_in_ActiveX_EXEs/article.asp).

Comment: @Scott:: So what else do you suggest? In my application I do have a long programme code. When the compiler executes that portion it takes almost 7 to 10 mins to execute. The user thninks that the applicatio has hanged. I want to do something which will prevail user from thinking so. If you can give me any idea to implement it.

Comment: @Rajdeep - I understand, and I suggest using and ActiveX DLL.  I'm just saying it's not easy to get right, so be careful.  You need to understand the fundamentals of sharing memory between threads.  It's a deep topic.

Comment: @Scott Thnkx .Appreciate your help

Comment: @Rajdeep: Multithreading is probably not answer to your problem, unless your user can do other meaningful things within your application at the same time. If you want only display some messages and/or progressbars to user, then consider designing your long procedure as fast cycle and update some UI elements in every cycle (using DoEvents statements optionally); maybe you can even implement some 'cancel' button. Of course this approach is not always possible, but often is and is much simpler to implement  than proper multithreading.

Comment: @Rajdeep - I am curious what process is taking 7-10 minutes to complete? Does this application access a database and have a very long running query. Just curious.

Comment: See "Use Timers to Work in the Background" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263516(VS.60).aspx rather than using a simple tight loop.  There are also other ways to use VB's async processing to avoid sitting in status buzz-loops awaiting activity completion.  Without more detail we can't be very specific about recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer to emulate threading. Not as efficient as actual threading, but I once designed a few applications (from VB 3.0 to VB 6.0) where I used that trick.