# Parallelisation in VB6?

Tags: vb6, parallel-processing

My code is very big, and it consumes many resources from the system - and I want to do something with this. I have an idea: to parallelise code - can I do that? If so, how? Please give specific examples.

Comment: Migrate to Visual Studio 2010, parallel computing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd441784.aspx#Parallel

Comment: possible duplicate of [parallel in vb6- how can i do it ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725598/parallel-in-vb6-how-can-i-do-it) @shirel -- it's no use just reposting a closed question, you'll only annoy people here.  Figure out why the question was closed, and post a question without the problems identified already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I understanding you correctly: you want a Visual Basic 6 application to implement multi threading, so that certain tasks can run "semi parallel"? If that is the case, the document [Multi-Threading In VB5 and VB6](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=1287) should get you started.

Comment: +1 for linking to Dan Appleman. It's excellent (if unavoidably a bit long). Of course running tasks in parallel will just mean taking even more "many resource from the system". It might help the GUI remain responsive, which may have been what shirel was asking about...?

Comment: This is another good question about running tasks in parallel in VB6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383162/to-use-thread-in-programming-in-vb6