# run one function after another function with 100ms delay (multi threading - VB6 - excel)

Tags: multithreading, vb6, excel-2007

is it possible running one function after another function with 100ms delay in separate thread.
i want to make a function to changing one cell in excel and run another function by 100ms delay by a separate thread in visual basic 6
tnx

Comment: VB6 does not support threading.  Creating a 100 msec Timer is certainly not a problem.

Comment: it seem that vb does not support the threading but the timer is not matter cause the time is important in thread

Comment: Einstein would not quite agree, time and matter matters.  What on Earth are you trying to say?

Comment: Is there any VB6 question here or is this just another overtagged VBA question trying to command attention?  It matters because the range of possible solutions varies quite a bit.

Comment: Basically I need something like that,setTimeout() Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API

In your delcarations section add this:

**Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)**

To use it:

**Sleep 100 ' to sleep for 0.1 second**

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by creating an ActiveX exe. See wqw's answer here, [To use thread in programming in vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383162/to-use-thread-in-programming-in-vb6). The 100ms second delay will be ~100ms delay. Depending on how accurate you want youe delay to be you can use the native VB timer accurate to somewhere arounf 10ms, or for higher resolution you can use a multi-media timer (makes it difficult to debug), or get a control that implements a high resolution timer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do multi threading in VB6, using ActiveX exes. These are "Out of process" so can be loaded and made to return immediately. Its many years since I did this, but I think I may have used a timer to allow me to load the class and return immediately, then have the class carry on working in its process.

This sort of a approach is horrible though - managing it in any sort of sensible way is a nightmare.

A much better option for you would be to write what you want in VB.Net (you should be fine to do it in an Express version I think), and set the assembly up to build to be COM compatible. Then you can reference this functionality in your VBA or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX DLL instances also run on their own thread, but all in one process.  So, you don't need the additional overhead of interprocess communication.  Of course, Excel would run in a separate process anyway.