# Is there a faster way to load 18k items into a Combo Dropdown?

Tags: vb6

I am having to fix some old VB6 code and one of the problem is that the app is loading 18k items into 3 different Combo Dropdowns on startup.  Needless to say, this takes a long time.  So I changed from using .AddItem method to using SendMessage APIs.  This cut down the time dramatically (by 60% or so), but each dropdown still takes 1.4 seconds to load, so the startup is still 5s.

I also tried to talk the users into not having all 18k there, but they insist that all entries must be there for quick lookup.

My questions...

1. Is there a faster way of loading that many items?
2. Anyway just to share the data between 3 combo boxes, rather than having to add 18k to each?
3. Any other solutions I may have overlooked.

Comment: Fastest loading time would be an owner-drawn combobox without `CBS_HASSTRINGS`. You just keep these 18k entries in an array and draw them on demand. The trouble is creating such a combobox in VB6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you already use [CB_ADDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (instead of CB_INSERTSTRING)

next item I suggest you to use: [CB_INITSTORAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

check that combobox has not [CBS_SORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CBS_SORT) set

during population - hide these boxes, it can speed up a little bit

and finally - make population of these comboboxes as 3 separate threads

Comment: @AngryHacker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383162/to-use-thread-in-programming-in-vb6 _You can use the CreateThread Win32 API but please keep in mind that the VB6 debugger cannot handle multiple threads._

Comment: But don't all the windows UI need to be on the same thread?  I'd be populating 3 combos on the same form.

Comment: ~CB_INITSTORAGE~ did help a bit.  It saved 0.15 s per each combo, which is pretty significant.

Comment: @AngryHacker there is no separate UI thread in windows, you can update your controls from any thread, just make sure that these updates are not conflicting (which is not your case)

Comment: @Ilya Bursov: There is a thread that a window is created on, the thread on which its messages are dispatched. When all of the app windows are created on a single thread, this thread is called the UI thread of the process. This is the case with VB6 (and most other applications).

Comment: @wqw right, all messages goes to single message loop, but it is not UI thread like in iOS or Windows Phone, you can update/send messages to visual controls from other threads

Comment: Same process `SendMessage` does not use the message queue but just calls wnd proc on whichever thread its called from, that's why its dangerous to "update" a control from a non-UI thread (one it's not created on and its messages are not dispatched on) because std and custom wnd procs are not thread safe per se.

Comment: @wqw in this particular case it is absolutely safe to run several threads, each will work with its own combobox

Answer (score 1):

SetRedraw to false during loading saves a lot of time.