# Using the .NET BackgroundWorker from VB6 fails with an AccessViolationException

Tags: vb6, backgroundworker, access-violation

The following MSDN example promises to demonstrate how to use the .NET BackgroundWorker from VB6 but it fails with an AccessViolationException.  The only workaround is to compile the VB6 code as P-code, but that is not a viable option for us.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109(VS.71).aspx

Here are [lots of details of the problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20130511193318/http://objectmix.com/dotnet/331152-using-background-threads-visual-basic-6-accessviolationexcep.html)

How can I fix the example to work without compiling the VB6 code as P-code?

Comment: The VB6 runtime is still fully supported - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx - and that's a Microsoft sample. You could report the problem to Microsoft technical support. If you have an MSDN subscription, you may be entitled to free support incidents.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  That is a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I [contacted Microsoft Tech Support](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/d8c83042-3bef-402a-a307-4108cf12ced7) and the official answer is that it is not possible.  That example is going to be pulled from MSDN.

Comment: The incorrect example is still there on MSDN almost two years later!

Comment: And it's still there now three years later. Here's a three year late +1 for your answer. It's depressing that this sample doesn't work.