# Backgroundworker with a netfx20wrapper?

Tags: .net, multithreading, vb6

Recently I have been given a task to program on vb 6(its an ActiveX Component). I am looking for way to a background worker in vb6 or more specifically multitasking . There is a article for this

Here is [a link from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

There it is mentioned the use of netfx20wrapper. Anyone who can tell me where I can get this. Searching on google is not helping.

I am not aware about this netfx20wrapper.

Comment: You asked this question 10 years too late.  The download link for the code is dead.

Comment: There are [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785169/using-the-net-backgroundworker-from-vb6-fails-with-an-accessviolationexception) with backgroundworker in VB6. See [this question for alternatives ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383162/to-use-thread-in-programming-in-vb6)

Comment: Lolz !! Hans Thanks for telling me this....that is why i asked this question...