# Does VB6 Timer control create separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, vb6, timer

Does the VB6 `Timer` control create a separate processing thread when it starts?

Comment: This question has good options on background processing in VB6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155517/cancelling-a-long-running-process-in-vb6-0-without-doevents

Comment: @MarkJ: would using a COM-wrapped BackgroundWorker thread be the easiest solution if I don't want to get too bogged down in VB6?

Comment: Yes, that's supposed to be easy. I've never actually done it myself though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VB6 Timer controls are not some kind of busy-wait loop running on a background thread.  They don't really "run" at all.

As far as I can tell when you set Enabled = True (or change Interval if it was 0) the control makes a SetTimer() call.  When you set Enabled = False (or set Interval to 0) it makes a KillTimer() call.

The normal VB6 message loop (which of course runs on the UI thread) handles incoming WM_TIMER messages by dispatching them to the associated Timer's event handler code.  Thus the code inside your event handler runs on the UI thread, blocking further message processing until exit.  Interval seems to be chopped to an unsigned 16-bit value - for legacy reasons (16-bit VB and Windows)?

Anything like a busy-wait loop coded in your program (all of your code runs on the UI thread) will of course block message processing, giving the illusion that Timers do not "fire."  Since WM_TIMER is a low priority message they do not stack up deeply in the message queue while you have the UI thread bound up:

> The WM_TIMER message is a low-priority message. The GetMessage and
>   PeekMessage functions post this message only when no other
>   higher-priority messages are in the thread's message queue.

Comment: Bob, what is the corollary of this? Can I put long processing tasks (such as a long stored procedure) in a Timer control an expect the UI to be responsive?

Comment: I agree, a Timer doesn't do anything to help you with a long-duration blocking operation. If you have a lengthy stored procedure use ADO's async Execute options instead of sync calls.  This lets ADO use an internal thread to handle the processing and waiting for completion.

Comment: @MartinJames: will putting `DoEvents` throughout the Timer code keep the UI responsive, thereby giving the illusion of multi-threading?

Comment: @Bob77 Do you have any kind of reference for this? I'm sure you're right I'd just like to see some official documentation so I can understand the issue myself

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677579(v=vs.85).aspx and related pages such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675083(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Answer (score 3):

No, the timer runs in the same thread as the window procedure, and thus the Visual Basic 6 program. This means that if you do processor intensive operations, you cannot rely on the WM_TIMER message being processed.

Comment: Also, to add to this, a pure VB6 way to get multithreading would be to create a VB6 ActiveX exe and configure and use it in a certain way.

Comment: @MafuJosh: how does this compare to using a COM-wrapped BackgroundWorker object via interop?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be a pure vb6 solution, but, that's up to you. Beyond that, I don't know. Looks like there are good examples out there (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) how to use the backgroundworker, so that is probably easier. With ActiveX exe, you'd have to basically write your own background worker. Also, the ActiveX exe method is more compatible with the VB6 IDE. The .NET thread can crash it if breakpoints are set in the thread (according to that link.) Also, I don't have a link describing using ActiveX exe for threading. Seems people use both ways.

Comment: @CJ7 I realise you've probably already written your code but using a separate ActiveX EXE to enable multithreading in VB6 has far fewer issues than using an interop wrapped background worker